# Getting an error in FileReference.save method

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex3, filereference

I am currently working in Flex 3.0 I am getting an error(screen shot is given below). I am using Flash Player Version 10.0

Currently I am calling the HTTPService and in the resultHandler of that HTTPService i am getting an error in method filereference.save() . because this method is called only when the MouseEvent or Keyboard event is occured.

Is there any solution to overcome this situation or in other words calling the filereference.save method in ResultHandler.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried dispatching a MouseEvent or KeyboardEvent "manually"?

Comment: no because i have never used that.. if possible will you please give me such code or URL? your help is precious for me..

Comment: dispatching MouseEvent thru code will not work

Comment: @OXMO456 I confirm: just tried, didn't work.

Comment: it works for other examples but for this kind of example its not working... I have tried that. Sorry RIAstar

Comment: I have solved that example my self. There isn't any solution for that so that i am returning the path not the data and call the navigatetoURL method for that. and from there i am downloading the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot. You need a click button of the user to get it done. Dispatching a MouseEvent is useless. Romi approach coud help you. But you need for security reasons to made it for a button click.

What I did.. was in the result retrive the file location and open it like an html page. Then you can download it. I see no other solution than forcing the user to click a button like Romi said.

```
var u:URLRequest = new URLRequest(event.result); 
navigateToURL(u, "_blank");
```

Comment: hi i have csv data as a string instead of event.result. the string is similar like that "a,b,c,d,e". what i need to do is save that string into the .csv file with name FullReport.csv... so have any idea about that?

Comment: What about generating the File in the server? And instead of returning all the string in your http service.. just return the URL/name of the file to apply what I said before. I had that problem again, in my case I Had to did it that way, the file could be so large, like 4gb.. impossible to trasmit it via remote object or something. You need a click from the user.. you will always get that error if you dont. If you wnat to use the .save method you need to use it that way.

Answer (score 5):

The reason for this is that you are no longer allowed to automatically trigger the display of file saving popups, except in the event of the user actually requesting this, via an event generated by the user. Here is some more info on the subject: http://www.bogdanmanate.com/2010/05/12/flex-error-2176-when-using-filereference/

I got around this problem using the solution described in the post, namely by using a Yes/No alert, to indicate to the user that the file has finished loading and it is ready for download and finally by asking him to confirm that he wants to save it locally. You might consider thins user-unfriendly, but it's really about security. And once you know how to trigger the event, you can figure out ways of bypassing this UI issue.

Have a great day!

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution might be to send the file to the server, then have the server send it back to the client which should trigger the browser's save/open dialog box. But if the file is created by flex then this is not ideal bandwidth-wise.